# Wrapping "img" with "p" CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to write plugin for CKEditor 4.1 which will wrap selected img with p tag. I found something about this in docs, but what's wrong?

```
var current = editor.getSelection();
if(current.getStartElement().getName() == 'img'){
    var p = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( 'p' );
    current.getSelectedElement().appendTo(p);
    alert('DONE');
}
```

When I click the button which calls this function, I'm getting empty space instead of img. What's wrong?

Comment: Why do you have to do this? CKEditor does this automatically in various moments (data loading, HTML/element insertions, pasting, etc.) if you're using default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
var current = editor.getSelection();
if(current.getStartElement().getName() == 'img'){
    var p = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( 'p', editor.document );
    p.insertBefore( current.getStartElement() );
    p.append( current.getStartElement() );
    alert('DONE');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for wrap < table> into < div class="table-wrapper">

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('table_wrapper', { 
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.on('insertElement', function (event) {
            if (event.data.getName() === 'table') {
                var div = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div').addClass('table-wrapper'); // Create a new div element to use as a wrapper.
                event.data.appendTo(div); // Append the original element to the new wrapper.
                event.data = div; // Replace the original element with the wrapper.
            }
        }, null, null, 1);
    }
});
```